# Geom bar graph and stat_count()

Tags: r

I would like to use a geom_bar for my data:

```
library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot(df, aes(x = word, y = freq)) + geom_bar(fill = "blue")
p + coord_flip() + labs(title = "Word frequency")
```

in data like this:

```
'data.frame':   953 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ word: Factor w/ 953 levels "music","play","movies playing",..: 75 70 81 405 291 455 192 470 22 269 ...
 $ freq: int  702 700 683 597 477 443 414 ...
```

but I receive this error for plot:

```
Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.
```

I found it is possible to use qplot which not using stat_count() but is there any way to use ggplot2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `stat = "identity"` :

```
library(ggplot2)
p = ggplot(df, aes(x = word, y = freq)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", fill = "blue")
p + coord_flip() + labs(title = "Word frequency")
```

By default, `geom_bar()` compute the frequencies of the dataset.

If you want to have it ordered, use that code before to sort the levels of the factor word:

```
df$word <- factor(df$word, levels = df$word[order(df$freq)])
```

In your case, as you have a dataset of 953 words, may I suggest a word cloud? A barchart may not be the most appropriate, here, as your label will be stacked and unreadable.